# How to pass results of bc to a variable

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, bc

I'm writing a script and I would like to pass the results from `bc` into a variable. I've declared 2 variables (`var1` and `var2`) and have given them values.  In my script I want to pass the results from `bc` into another variable say `var3` so that I can work with `var3` for other calculations.  So far I have been able write the result to a file which is not what I'm looking for and also I've been able to echo the result in the terminal but I just want to pass the result to a variable at moment so that I can work with that variable.

```
echo "scale=2;$var1/var2" | bc
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using bash, you'd better use an here string instead of a pipe as in:

```
bc <<< "scale=2;$var1/$var2"
```

This will save you a subshell.

Then, to store the output of a command, use a command substitution:

```
answer=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$var1/$var2")
```

## Edit.

If you want something even cooler than `bc`, here's dc (reverse polish calculator):

```
answer=$(dc <<< "2k $var1 $var2/p")
```

Comment: Yes I'm using bash, can you please clarify on the subshell?  Is there a disadvantage?

Comment: Each time you use a pipe `|` the command on the right of the pipe is executed in a subshell, and it takes resources to open a new subshell (it's like opening a new instance of bash to execute that command). If you can avoid it, avoid it. Here, piping an `echo` to `bc` will run the command `bc` in a subshell and is, in some sense, retarded (no offence), since bash has the wonderful here-string construct `<<<` to avoid stupid things like these.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Then again, if you cared about resource usage, you'd use `/bin/sh` (dash) instead of bash, but dash doesn't have `<<<`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information!! This is good information to know regarding preserving resources and subshells.  I greatly appreciate you input.

Comment: @Gilles please don't distort the discussion, you know I'm talking about _useless_ and _avoidable_ wastages of resource. Because going further in your direction, if I cared about resources I would not have a computer at all. Please let's be serious, so let me ask you a serious question: how can you (easily) check for the return code of `bc` if it's in a subshell like in your answer?

Comment: @gniourf, thanks for your info!! really..it was helpful

Comment: See a discussion with benchmarks on [unix.se]: [echo vs <<<, or Useless Use of echo in Bash Award?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59007/59063#59063) It seems that if you care about performance, you should use a heredoc, not a herestring, and most importantly you should use dash or ksh. Using `<<<` in bash is a waste of resources (but not an important one).

Comment: By the way, you can get the output of `bc` with `var3=$(echo … | bc)`. It's in `$?`, same as with `var3=$(bc <<<…)`.

Comment: [Stephane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59007/echo-vs-or-useless-use-of-echo-in-bash-award/59063#comment81486_59063) explains why `<<<` is slow: it creates a temporary file, which is slower than a pipe. The data has to come from somewhere after all.

Comment: @Gilles just compare `time for i in {1..10000}; do : <<< ""; done` with `time for i in {1..10000}; do echo "" | : ; done`, you'll see a dramatic difference. Then you're right, a heredoc is slightly faster than a herestring. But it's more awkward to type as a one-liner.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Now try it with the actual command here instead of an overly simplified example (which doesn't run an external command and doesn't read the data). With bash, and `/tmp` on tmpfs, I don't see any difference between `echo … |` and `<<<`. With ksh, `<<<` is indeed measurably faster (and faster than bash).

Comment: @Gilles ok, then continue to use `echo | ...`. I really don't care.

Comment: @Gilles with `<<<`, it's not just about slowness! It's also always a problem on read-only environments, because on more complex scripts, your screen will be flooded with ugly error messages. And here's another thing people sometimes have difficulties to understand: this may happen __even under `root`! Because even `root` can't write everywhere, if partitions are *mounted* read-only. Very common on other companies' systems that you only have restricted access to. Likewise, recovery consoles would show that behavior by default as well.

Answer (score 10):

[Command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) stores the output of a command into a variable.

```
var3=$(echo "scale=2;$var1/$var2" | bc)
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me exactly where I wanted to be, after probably an hour of researching. Thanks