# Creating files with multiple variables

Tags: bash, scripts

I have been trying to write an executable script which creates files containing multiple variables.

Here, `x` varies from 1 to 25, z from 5 to 7 at steps of 0.1, whilst `y` and `w` are constants. Hence, for each value of `x`, there must be 21 files. I have tried the below, however I can't get my head around how such a nested for loop should work.

```bash
mkdir dir
for ((i=1;i<=25;i++)); do
    printf 'x=%s\ny=4\n' "$i"
    for ((j=5;j<=7;j=j+0.1));do
        printf 'z=%s\nw=4\n' "$j" > dir/diles_$i_$j.txt
done
```

Also, how can I make this executable? I am working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does my answer helps you? Please update your answer if it's not the case, or tick it as *accepted* (or post a comment if it's near to solve your issue)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution :

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir dir
for ((i=1;i<=25;i++)); do
    printf 'x=%s\ny=4\n' "$i"
    for ((j=50;j<=70;j++));do
        t=$(bc <<< "scale=1; $j/10")
        printf 'z=%s.1f\nw=4\n' "$t" > dir/diles_$i\_$t.txt
    done
done
```

Explanation :

- Bash works **only** with integer, so you can't do your loop with a float / decimal (you see that I just use a division by 10 below)
- We use `bc` command, which convert integers operation (a division for example) in order to get float; `scale` operator show how many decimal we want to have (here, 1 is suffisant in order to not have many `0`, like `bc -l` do)
- we need to add a `\\` in the filename because it didn't take care of the `i` to name files ifnot

---

Also, I pointed that your 1st `printf` command just print result like that in the terminal, probably you would add them inside each file (instead of terminal display), so you must use the code below in this case :

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir dir
for ((i=1;i<=25;i++)); do
    for ((j=50;j<=70;j++));do
        t=$(bc <<< "scale=1; $j/10")    
        printf 'x=%s\ny=4\n' "$i" > dir/diles_$i\_$t.txt
        printf 'z=%s.1f\nw=4\n' "$t" >> dir/diles_$i\_$t.txt
    done
done
```

NB : the `>>` operator or the 2nd `printf` command is important here (1st `printf` didn't care, depends only if you want to take care of previous data - `>>` -, or not - `>`), because if you use just a `>` operand, you would erase all previous data (so output of the 1st `printf` would be removed)

Sources :

- [How do I use floating point division in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash)
- [How to pass results of bc to a variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229446/how-to-pass-results-of-bc-to-a-variable)